# Importing geometry package messes up line breaking behavior of \texthl

Tags: geometry, latex3, soul, parskip

It looks like uncommenting line 6 of the code below suppresses the line breaking behavior of `\texthl`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage[showframe, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{soul}

\setmonofont{Courier New}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85, 0.85, 0.85}
\sethlcolor{bg}

\begin{document}
    This is some inline code that uses LaTeX special characters, and
    breaks a line
    \texthl{\texttt{\textbackslash newcommand\{test\}\{out\}}}

    This is some inline code that uses LaTeX special characters, and
    \texthl{\texttt{\textbackslash newcommand\{test\}\{out\}}}


    This is a path that alsodsad kljaskl djaslkdj aslkdj aksljd klaj
    sdlak sklajdaklsjd kalsdj klasjd
    \texthl{\texttt{Cas\{dals\textbackslash dalskdaslkdaslkdlaskdlask}}

\end{document}
```

Here is **without** the `geometry` import:

[image]

And here is **with** the `geometry` import:

[image]

How can I get `geometry` to respect the margin even when I'm using `texthl`?

Comment: that has nothing to do with geometry, you changed the linewidth and now your words fall so that TeX doesn't find suitable hyphenation points.

Comment: Doesnt geometry change the linewidth? How can I remedy it?

Comment: sure it changes it, after all you set `margin=2cm`.

Comment: How can I get TeX to linebreak such that the 2 cm margin is respected?

Comment: insert hyphenation points with `\-` see the soul documentation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see what you're saying. It does work when I introduce hyphenation. I did run into a weird situation though. Consider the following, which is supposed to render as `x = 3` and hyphenate at any position: `\texthl{\texttt{x\- \-=\- \-3}}`. For some reason it only highlights up to but NOT INCLUDING the equals sign. Any idea why this occurs?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I made a new question related to that. Would greatly appreciate your input https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656016/why-does-highlighting-stop-working-when-i-introduce-hyphenation-and-text-includi