# Why does highlighting stop working when I introduce hyphenation and text including an equals sign?

Tags: line-breaking, geometry, highlighting, soul

I'm using `soul`'s `\texthl` in combination with `\texttt` to render inline code that can break at arbitrary hyphenation points when it reaches the end of a line. To simulate the "verbatim" aspect of inline code I'm basically escaping any special characters (`\${}_&%#~^`) that may appear within the verbatim text.

Here's an example of what I was able to achieve:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{soul}

\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85, 0.85, 0.85}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\sethlcolor{bg}

\begin{document}

     aklsdklasj asdkj alskjd aslkj dalskjd asldjd asad ldasd  sd pjwed e jope pojep 
     ojepoj ejpm pwj slakdj as  \texthl{\texttt{\textbackslash \-\-n\-e\-w\-c\-o\-m\-m\-a\-n\-d\-\{\-t\-e\-s\-t\-\}\-\{\-o\-u\-t\-\}}}
\end{document}
```

Which compiles as follows using `latexmk -lualatex test.tex`:

[image]

Unfortunately, if I try to render `x = 3` the highlighting doesn't work anymore:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{soul}

\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85, 0.85, 0.85}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\sethlcolor{bg}

\begin{document}

     aklsdklasj asdkj alskjd aslkj dalskjd asldjd asad ldasd  sd pjwed e jope pojep 
     ojepoj ejpm pwj slakdj as  \texthl{\texttt{\textbackslash \-\-n\-e\-w\-c\-o\-m\-m\-a\-n\-d\-\{\-t\-e\-s\-t\-\}\-\{\-o\-u\-t\-\}}}

    \texthl{\texttt{x\- \-=\- \-3}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Does anyone know why?

Comment: As you use lualatex: drop soul and use lua-ul instead. That is much less fragile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Folowing up and expanding on @UlrikeFischer's suggestion, you may want to start using the `lua-ul` package instead of `soul`. I would further like to suggest that you load the `xurl` package and enclose the longish strings in `\path` wrappers to allow line breaks at arbitrary locations. That way, you can write

```
\highLight{\path|\newcommand{\test}{out}|}
```

instead of

```
\texthl{\texttt{\textbackslash \-\-n\-e\-w\-c\-o\-m\-m\-a\-n\-d\-\{\-\textbackslash\-t\-e\-s\-t\-\}\-\{\-o\-u\-t\-\}}}
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Courier New}

\usepackage{luacolor} % repalcement for 'xcolor'
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85, 0.85, 0.85}

\usepackage{lua-ul}  % replacement for 'soul' package
\LuaULSetHighLightColor{bg}

\usepackage{xurl} % for \path macro, allow line breaks at arbitrary locations

\begin{document}
aklsdklasj asdkj alskjd aslkj dalskjd asldjd asadcd   
pwj slakdj as \highLight{\path|\newcommand{\test}{out}|}

\smallskip
\highLight{\path+x=3+}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to work very well, though I think that I prefer to go with [patching mintinline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655908/breaking-lines-resulting-from-mintinline-or-verb/656034#656034). That's a lovely suggestion to use `\path` from `xurl`. Any idea why this macro isn't listed in the `xurl` [documentation](https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/xurl/doc/xurl.pdf)?

Comment: @user32882 - Why-type questions are best posed to the authors of the piece of software in question. I can only guess that the because `xurl` is "just" [!] a front-end to the `url` package, the author of the `xurl` package didn't want to risk coming across as stealing anyone else's intellectual contributions. That said, I don't think it would have hurt to provide a sentence such as "Because the`xurl` package loads the `url` package, all of the macros defined by the `url` package, including `\path` and `\urldef`, are also available."